# Существует ли ограничение на кол-во ответов?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Я сегодня опубликовал некоторое кол-во ответов. Вначале все было хорошо и стабильно, ответы публиковались без проблем. В последних двух ответах кнопка "Отправить ответ" уж очень долго висела серой и крутился скролл. После перезагрузки страницы, я опять попадал в поле создания ответа и при повторном нажатии на кнопку отправки ответа, вылезала капча с роботом. И после прохождения капчи у меня по факту было опубликовано два ответа. Не могу понять в чем причина такого поведения. Перебоев с сетью вроде бы нету.

Comment: Капча глючит если вкладка долго открыта.